# Equal axis labels and ranges for all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I'm plotting an image with 4 subplots like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.xlabel('Label_x')
plt.ylabel('Label_y')
plt.plot(something_1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.xlabel('Label_x')
plt.ylabel('Label_y')
plt.plot(something_2)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.xlabel('Label_x')
plt.ylabel('Label_y')
plt.plot(something_3)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.xlabel('Label_x')
plt.ylabel('Label_y')
plt.plot(something_4)

plt.show()
```

As you can see the only thing that changes among subplots is the last line (ie: what's being plotted) but the axis' labels and ranges stay the same.

How can I set the axis labels and ranges *once* and have it apply to all my subplots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `plt.subplots`:

```
In [36]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: fig, axes=plt.subplots(2, 2)
    ...: for ax in axes.ravel(): #ravel axes to a flattened array 
    ...:     ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    ...:     ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
    ...:     ax.set_xlabel('Label_x')
    ...:     ax.set_ylabel('Label_y')
    ...: plt.show()
    ...:
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a while ago, but for anyone seeing this post now, I would add to @zhangxaochen answer to note that in `plt.subplots` command also has the parameters `sharex` and `sharey`. So if you want, you could just use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes=plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex = True, sharey = True)
for ax in axes.ravel(): #ravel axes to a flattened array 
# Do plotting here
plt.show()
```